# How to recover gracefully when Android MediaPlayer goes into error loop: error(-38,0)

Tags: android, media-player

I have a MediaPlayer that plays with the following code:

```
 private void playVideo() {
    if (videoURI == null) {
        showToast("Please, set the video URI in HelloAndroidActivity.java in onClick(View v) method");
    } else {
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    player.setOnErrorListener(new OnErrorListener()
                    {
                        @Override
                        public boolean onError(MediaPlayer mp,
                                int what, int extra) {
                            Log.e("MEDIAPLAYER ERRORS",
                            "what: " + what + "  extra: "   + extra);

                          return false;
                        }
                    });
                    Log.d("video","---+ in main run");
                    player.setDataSource(videoURI);
                    player.prepare();
                    player.reset();
                } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
                    Log.d("video","---+ illegal arg");
                    showToast("Error while playing video");
                    Log.i(TAG, "==========              IllegalArgumentException ===========");
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                    Log.d("video","---+ illegal state");
                    showToast("Error while playing video");
                    Log.i(TAG, "========== IllegalStateException ===========");
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    Log.d("video","---+ general error");
                    showToast("Error while playing video. Please, check your network connection.");
                    Log.i(TAG, "========== IOException ===========");
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }).start();
    }
}
```

On error, my app goes into an infinite error loop with the following messages:

```
 03-05 13:27:23.035: E/MediaPlayer(6289): stop called in state 0
 03-05 13:27:23.035: E/MediaPlayer(6289): error (-38, 0)
 03-05 13:27:23.035: E/MediaPlayer(6289): Error (-38,0)
 03-05 13:27:23.043: E/MEDIAPLAYER ERRORS(6289): what: -38  extra: 0
```

What is the best way to recover from the error that is caught?  Should I abort the mediaplayer and if so how do I accomplish this?  Also how can I stop from going into this error loop in the first place?

Thanks!

Comment: Does it ever play the video correctly? if not my guess is encoding error. Try converting the video to h.264 mp4 file. If it does play correctly sometimes, but does this loop others. Try returning true from your onErrorListener().

Comment: It does play correctly sometimes and the videos I am playing are encoded for h.264.  I returned true from the listener and I still get the same errors.

Comment: What device are you testing on? While it is spamming this in the logs does it make the rest of the device unreponsive? Or is there no indication (other than the logs) that anything is wrong?

Comment: yes the device becomes unresponsive when the logs are being spammed.  This happens on a droid, droid2 and galaxy tab.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is there something missing from your code? It doesn't seem to me like it would ever actually start the MediaPlayer anywhere in what you've posted.

It also seems odd to me that you call

```
player.reset();
```

after the others. I would think this would undo the setDataSource(), and prepare() that you just got finished with. Try moving reset so that it is the first one called.

and try putting this in your onErrorListener callback:

```
player.reset();
player.setDataSource(videoURI);
player.prepare();
```

That way it will just try to remake the whole thing when it gets this error.